# Why do I get `(Object) CRM_Contact_Page_DashBoard` at ~/dashboard?

Tags: drupal, dashboard

I'm running Civi 5.19.alpha1 locally, installed using `buildkit` with `drupal-clean` on my laptop running Ubuntu 19.04.

So I just manually installed or updated a bunch of Drupal modules (I started off just wanting to install `webform-civicrm` and ran down the rabbit hole of other required modules).

I now see only `(Object) CRM_Contact_Page_DashBoard` at `http://localhost:7979/civicrm/dashboard`.

I also see this message at `http://localhost:7979/`:

`hook_civicrm_pageRun called. This hook is called before a CiviCRM page is rendered. Note that this does not execute on every CiviCRM page in the general sense. CiviCRM's pages are classified as either 'Forms' or 'Pages', and this only runs on pages classified as 'Pages'. If you are not sure if a particular page is a Page, test it by adding some temporary debug code to /CRM/Utils/Hook.php`

I've run `drush updb` and get `No database updates required`,  `drush cvupcfg` and get `Config successfully updated`.

Been Googling around, looked in Civi docs, checked StackExchange, not figured out the problem yet.

I could and maybe just should go back and uninstall/delete the modules I just installed, of course, but prefer to not have to re-install later.

UPDATE: see the answer below. I had enabled the Drupal `civicrm_developer` and `Devel` modules, though of course, I did not have to, to enable the `webform_civicrm_integration` module. I was enabling other Drupal modules that looked useful.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you enabled the `civicrm_developer` Drupal module.  I would disable that.

Comment: Yup, that was the cause. Disabled the module and back to my dashboard. Thanks Jon!

Comment: For folks coming across this, see this for more re what the module does - https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=19400.0.html